# how to create criteria on parent's childs list in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have Parent Domain and a Child Domain

```
  class Parent{
        static hasMany = [childs: Child]
  }

  class Child{

  }
```

In database

```
  Parent_Id  Parent_Age  Parent_Name
      1        20          AAAA
      2        25          BBBB

   Child_id  Child_Age   Child_Name  Parent_Id(F.K.)
      1        2           00000       1
      2        6           11111       1
      3        5           22222       1 
      4        3           33333       2
      5        4           44444       2
      5        9           55555       2
```

Now I have parent object.

```
    def parentInstance = Parent.get(1);
    def childsList     = parentInstance?.childs  ---> //from this list here  
                                                      //i want to get             
                                                     // only those childs  
                                                     //whose age is greater  
                                                     //than or equal to 3.  
                                                             Or
                                                     // greater than or 
                                                     //equal to 5.
```

Is it possible to do that on queried list .

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Parent parentInstance = Parent.get(1);

List<Child> childList = Child.createCriteria().list(){
     parent{
         eq("id", 1 as Long)
     }

     or{
         ge("age", 3)

         ge("age", 5)
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but i need only those childs whose parent id is 1

Comment: As i am getting like  def childsList     = parentInstance?.childs

Comment: yes this will give you all chidren whose parent is parent with id 1. ` eq("parent", parentInstance)`

Comment: could not resolve property: parent of  com.mydomain.Child like error  giving

Comment: No signature of method: com.mydomain.Parent.parent() is applicable for argument types:  its giving like error

Comment: What is the field name in the Child object that refers to its parent? please post the full code for your domain objects.

Comment: How can i say grails created one more table for mapping parent_child

Comment: Actually grails created one more table for mapping parent_child

Comment: No you dont need to do so, just add `static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]` if you are not having that on your Child class then the above code should work for you.

Comment: any other solution, because if add belongsTo it afftects database

Comment: if so you can just add `Parent parent` in child

Comment: Then it would not affect database

Comment: well then it means you dont hv child that satisfy the criteria, but you cant get null, you may get empty list.

Comment: yes it is giving empty list but i hv data i am passing 3 . In child table 5 and 6 is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77723/discussion-between-codehx-and-atul).

Comment: I hv another question can i ask

Comment: Okay you can but consider accepting my answer if it helped u